# Why does the console.log show an empty array when using the embed tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load an inventory page I created inside of another page that I created. I utilize the  tag to do this by dynamically calling the  link through javascript. However, when I do this, the DOM of the embedded page appears to be empty as the console.log call shows an empty array. When I load the inventory page directly to the browser, the code functions as intended and shows an array of divs.

I have a function in a file called ItemAPI.js for my website below:

```
function fillInventory() {
    const weaponSlots = document.querySelectorAll('.weapon');
    console.log(weaponSlots);
    //Once loaded do other things.
}
```

It looks at my HTML page below:

```
<head>
    <script src= 'ItemAPI.js' type = module></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class= 'inventory'>
       <div class = 'weapon'></div>
       <div class = 'weapon'></div>
       <div class = 'weapon'></div>
       <div class = 'weapon'></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

When I test the page using LiveServer through VSCode the list of divs with the class of weapons print to the console as the code dictates. However when I load the page from another page shown below:

```
<head>
    <script src= 'AnotherJSFile.js' type = module></script>
</head>
<body>
    <embed src="../inventory-screen/inventory-screen.html" borderframe= 0>
</body>
```

An empty array is logged to the console. My question is how does embed work that the divs are logged correctly when directly loading the html file to the browser and not logged correctly when loaded through the  tag?

Comment: Your HTML is not valid, you should be consistent with your single or double quote usage.

Comment: _"My question is how does embed work"_ - pretty much the same way as an iframe. You have a completely independent document in there, with its own DOM.

Comment: Your problem lies here in script tag ` <script src= 'AnotherJSFile.js" type = module></script>`. src starts with single quote and ends with double quote. As problem in `<script src= 'ItemAPI.js type = module></script>`

Comment: None of those are the problem. The code works and runs. Obviously, when I was putting it into the question I made a couple typos, which I will edit out. @CBroe, your answer comment doesn't do much to answer the question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Other_embedding_technologies might be helpful.

Comment: @connexo Thank you for that resource, it still didn't answer my question as to what is exactly going on, but changing the tag from embed to iframe did make what I want happen work. I'm still getting an Uncaught TypeError error, but then the code seems to run a second time and it works. So, I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: From what I've read in 1 minute about the embed tag (disclaimer: never used), it's not meant to be used to embed HTML content.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I changed the tag to iframe. Still unsure exactly what is going on. I just need to work through the styling of it now. It adds scroll bars to the div that I don't want. :)

Comment: `scrolling="no"` attribute on iframe, or `overflow: hidden` in CSS.